# How do you make a file writeable in VB?

Tags: vb6, permissions

I'm looking for the simplest way to test if a file is writeable, and if it is read-only to change its access permissions to make it writeable.

Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons that a file may not be writeable, for example:

- It's write protected
- It's on a read-only medium (e.g. a CD-ROM)
- The user account used for running the code doesn't have write access to the file
- The file is on a file share where writing is not allowed

You can check for some of those, but the only way to test for sure is to actually try to open the file for writing.

You can use the [GetAttr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hds568h4.aspx) and [SetAttr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5wx7516.aspx) functions to look for and change the read-only flag.

Some reasons for a file not being writeable can not be fixed at all (like a file on a CD-ROM), or can't be fixed from your program. If the user account doesn't have write permission to the file, it's unlikely that it has permission to change the permissions...

Comment: Files are sometime not writeable in our case because they are copied through a process we don't control. So we just want to cover all cases.

Comment: If the file is still being copied, so that you expect it to be writable in a while, the application could just sleep for a while an try again (or queue the file for later).

Answer (score 3):

**Using GetAttr and SetAttr**

```
Dim attributes As VbFileAttribute

attributes = GetAttr("C:\foo.txt")
If (attributes And vbReadOnly) Then
  attributes = attributes - vbReadOnly
  SetAttr "C:\foo.txt", attributes
End If
```

**Using the FileSystemObject** (requires a project reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime)

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fil As File

Set fil = fso.GetFile("C:\foo.txt")
If (fil.attributes And ReadOnly) Then
  fil.attributes = fil.attributes - ReadOnly
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

```
'Getting and Setting File Attributes

Declare Function SetFileAttributes Lib "kernel32" _
 Alias "SetFileAttributesA" (ByVal lpFileName As _
 String, ByVal dwFileAttributes As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetFileAttributes Lib "kernel32" _
 Alias "GetFileAttributesA" (ByVal lpFileName As _
 String) As Long

Public Function GetAttributes(Filename As String, _
 Archive As Boolean, Hidden As Boolean, _
 ReadOnly As Boolean, System As Boolean)

    'Dimension and setup some variables.
    Dim Data As Long
    Archive = False: Hidden = False: ReadOnly = False

    'Get Data and check for success.
    Data = GetFileAttributes(Filename)
    If Data = 0 Then GetAttributes = 0 Else GetAttributes = 1

    'Work out what it is.
    If Data = 128 Then Exit Function
    If Data - 32 >= 0 Then Archive = True: Data = Data - 32
    If Data - 4 >= 0 Then System = True: Data = Data - 4
    If Data - 2 >= 0 Then Hidden = True: Data = Data - 2
    If Data - 1 >= 0 Then ReadOnly = True: Data = Data - 1

End Function

Public Function SetAttributes(Filename As String, _
Archive As Boolean, Hidden As Boolean, _
ReadOnly As Boolean, System As Boolean)

    'Dimension a Variable.
    Dim Data As Long

    'Work out what Data should be.
    Data = 0
    If Archive = True Then Data = Data + 32
    If Hidden = True Then Data = Data + 2
    If ReadOnly = True Then Data = Data + 1
    If System = True Then Data = Data + 4
    If Data = 0 Then Data = 128

    'Set the attributes and check for success.
    SetAttributes = SetFileAttributes(Filename, Data)

End Function
```